# External USB powered DVD writer doesn’t power up using macOS Catalina when using direct USB C to mini USB cable

Tags: catalina, usb, external-disk, power

*I have owned four different models of the new MacBook Air’s (2018, 2019, 2020 and 2023) running macOS Mojave (10.14), macOS Catalina (10.15) and macOS Sonoma (14.4) and noticed a strange issue today when connecting a USB C powered device.*

---

On my 2020 MacBook Air running macOS Catalina 10.15.6, when connecting an external USB powered DVD writer (LG GP50NB40) to read a CD, it simply doesn’t power up or get recognized by the system. I have tried this out on both of the two USB C ports on the MacBook Air and the results are the same.

The green light on the front of the DVD writer blinks and you can hear a sound that sounds like the drive is attempting to “rev up” but isn’t getting enough power. The connection is being made directly via a USB C to mini USB cable (1m long); the same cable I have used successfully in the past on other MacBook Air models that ran that ran macOS Mojave.

Here is the really weird part; I *could* get the drive to mount if I connected some adapter or hub to the cables:

- **USB A to mini USB (via USB A to USB C Adapter)**: If I took a USB C to USB A adapter and used a USB A to mini USB (1m long) cable… Et voila! The drive is recognized and I can mount the audio CD!
- **USB C to mini USB (via USB C Hub)**: Ditto when using a USB C hub with the USB C to mini USB cable… It all worked!

But a direct connection via a USB C to mini USB cable consistently fails. Why is this? And what — if anything — can be done to allow me to use the USB C to mini USB cable? Is this some kind of macOS USB power issue managed by the OS or something else?

I have tried [resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) as well as [zapping the PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) to no avail. Below is the device info from the system report for the drive if/when it was mounted:

```
Portable Super Multi Drive:

  Product ID:   0x1887
  Vendor ID:    0x0e8d  (MediaTek Inc.)
  Version:  0.00
  Serial Number:    M00I9K20652
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/s
  Manufacturer: Hitachi-LG Data Storage Inc
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 8
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    500
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Here is a pic of the power consumption — via an inline USB C power measurement dongle — for a direct USB C connection when it doesn’t work:

[image: USB C Direct]

Power consumption from a USB A to mini USB (via USB A to USB C adapter) when it works:

[image: USB C to USB A Adapter]

Power consumption from a USB C to mini USB cable (via USB C Hub) when it works:

[image: USB C Via Hub]